# How to mathematically denote common elements

Tags: mathematical-statistics, notation

I have 5 lists collected over 5 years as follows.

```
year1 = [8, 1, 5, 6]
year2 = [6, 8]
year3 = [8, 5, 6]
year4 = [9, 2, 8, 1, 6]
year5 = [8, 1, 6]
```

I extracted the elements that are common to all the 5 lists as; `[8, 6]`

I want to denote the above process using a mathematical notation. i.e. my output is the elements that are commeon to all the years.

However, due to my lack of knowledge in notations I am not sure how to do it, in a more compact way.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's reasonable to treat them as sets (e.g. each distinct element can only ever appear once, order doesn't matter, etc), then you can use [set-intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29#Notation_and_terminology) to denote the elements in common:

$A_1 = \{8,1,5,6\}$

$A_2 = \{6,8\}$

... etc

Then $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5 = \{6,8\}$

If you have a large number of sets to take the intersection of, you could write $A_1\cap A_2\cap \ldots \cap A_n$ as

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$$